# Virtualenvs won't work after switching from 64 to 32-bit Python on OSX

Tags: python, virtualenv

I re-installed Python 2.7 with the official DMG installer from python.org because I needed to use a pre-compiled binary which choked on my 64-bit Python install..
(Recompiling it to run in 64-bit is too difficult for me, not an option)

It worked, the Python mac Installer fixes all the links, so my new python install is 32-bit, but all the virtualenv I had created with the 64-bit Python cannot use Python anymore, here is the output :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
Referenced from: /Users/dom/django/.virtualenvs/lepoc/bin/python
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/dom/django/.virtualenvs/lepoc/bin/../.Python: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
/Users/dom/django/.virtualenvs/lepoc/bin/../.Python: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
Trace/BPT trap
```

Is there a possible fix (like re-linking something) or do I have to re-create all my virtualenv ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with recreating them. The "python" executable in the bin folder is an executable and is probably specific to your architecture and/or python binary. You can save all installed python packages and reinstall them in the new virtual environment using pip:

```
pip freeze -E lepoc > requirements.txt
pip install -E newve -r /path/to/pip-requirements.txt
```

See also http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/

Comment: Hum, that's what I'd like to avoid...furthermore, I can't even call `pip freeze` as python is not available...

Comment: You don't need to run pip within the virtualenv, you run it in the context of your system python interpreter. Also, I don't see any downsides as all packages are re-installed, it shouldn't be much work. I'd rather go with clean and a little extra effort than risk getting weird side-effects later when cpython stuff that was compiled as 32bit code fails.

Comment: using these commands had a weird effect , but I just used pip freeze on my server and re-created the virtualenv, everything in place now, thanks